# drupal 7 SSO Integration with LDAP

Tags: drupal

I was able to integrate LDAP SSO to drupal 7 also i am using mod_auth_sspi(mod_auth_sspi-1.0.4-2.2.2) for authentication mechanism.
But if I try to restart apache, it saying error message:

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies
```

The httpd.conf file also contains:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
# Pass NTLM authentication to Apache
LoadModule sspi_auth_module modules/mod_auth_sspi.so
<IfModule !mod_auth_sspi.c>
 LoadModule sspi_auth_module modules/mod_auth_sspi.so
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [Drupal LDAP](https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap) module? This should support everything you need for authentication.

Note that LDAP isn't the same as SSO. For that you can use something like [SimpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have an error in you Apache configuration and/or apache is not able to reach LDAP.

But firstly note that SSO is not the same as LDAP - LDAP is an authorization and authentication method and approach and SSO (single-sign-on) is a centralization of these methods - e.g. user is able to browse different websites withou having to login and/or having to create additional accounts.

More information could be available in the apache error log.  If not change your logging level to debug (or possibly syslog if apache error log is not configured).